# how to reduced image view size in horizontal recycler-view adapter in android

Tags: android

```
class MutualLooperIconAdapter(private val imagelist: MutableList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MutualLooperIconAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(private val itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(image: String, position: Int, imageSize: Int) {
//            profile_image?.setImageResource(R.drawable.user)
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    profile_image?.let {
                        Glide.with(context).load(image).apply(RequestOptions().override(32, 24)) .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(it)
                    }
                }

                1 -> {
                    profile_image?.let {
                        Glide.with(context).load(image).apply(RequestOptions().override(24, 16)) .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(it)
                    }

                }

                1 -> {
                    profile_image?.let {
                        Glide.with(context).load(image).apply(RequestOptions().override(16, 12)) .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(it)
                    }

                }

                else -> {
                    profile_image?.let {
                        Glide.with(context).load(image).apply(RequestOptions().override(12, 8)) .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into(it)
                    }

                }
            }

//            if (position == 4) {
//                relative?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//                tvCount?.text = "${imageSize - 4}"
//            } else {
//                relative?.visibility = View.GONE
//            }

        }

        private var profile_image: RoundedImageView? = null
        private var relative: RelativeLayout? = null
        private var tvCount: TextView? = null

        init {
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
            relative = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative)
            tvCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_overlapuser_profile_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(imagelist[position], position, imagelist.size)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imagelist.size
    }
}
```

this is my adapter and i am calling like this

```
 private fun showAllMutualLooper() {
        if (mutualLooperList.size > 0) {
            binding.rclyMultiuser.apply {
                layoutManager =
                    LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
                addItemDecoration(OverlapDecoration())
                adapter = MutualLooperIconAdapter(mutualLooperList)
            }
        }
    }
```

currently  item is showing like this
[image]

I have fixed width of recyclerview 80dp so its showing only 4 item visible but i want some thing like this when 5 item is visible then it should show position 0 bigger  then position 1 lesser than 0 position and position 2 lesser than position and so on .
like below screen
[image]

can any one please help me how we can reduced image size recycler-view  adapter item imageview.

Thanks